# Is there a math formula for 16 person, doubles, 3 round, round robin

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

Having tried to figure this out myself, but failing, is there a matrix where in a 3 round, 16 player, doubles tennis, round robin, that players do not end up on court with the same players more than once.

I don’t think it’s possible but perhaps one of you math brainiacs could prove me wrong.  I spent 30 years as a doctor but failed math from grade 11 onward.  Stats - no problem.  Physics - no problem.  Math - eeeeeyyyaawww!

Comment: Do you mean there are three rounds in which four games take place simultaneously?  Also, am I right that the condition mean that no two player play in the same game twice?  That is, every player plays with nine different people?

Comment: After AB vs. CD, is also AX vs BY disallowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrange the $16$ people in a square:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 &1 &2 &3 &4\\
 &5 &6 &7 &8\\
 &9 &10 &11 &12\\
&13 &14 &15 &16 
\end{bmatrix} $$

For the first round, group them according to the rows. For the second round, group them according to the columns.  For the third, group them accoring to the broken diagonals:

$$1,6,11,16$$
$$2,7,12,13$$
$$3,8,9,14$$
$$4,5,10,15$$

Split the groups of four into two teams however you like.

**EDIT**

Actually, this can be extended to a five-round tournament in which each player plays with each of the other $15$ exactly once.  Identify each player with a point in the affine plane over the field with $4$ elements.  There are $5$ lines through the origin.  For each round, consider the pencil of lines parallel to one of the lines through the origin, and group the players according to the lines.  Split the four players into two teams arbitrarily.

Just for fun, I computed the full design where there are five rounds, and each player plays once with each of the $15$ other players.  The table below shows the results.  The rows indicate players and the columns are rounds.  The table entries may be taken to be courts, but the important point is that players with the same letter play in the same match.

```
    1 2 3 4 5
 1: A A A A A
 2: A B B B B
 3: A C C C C
 4: A D D D D
 5: B A B C D
 6: B B A D C
 7: B C D A B
 8: B D C B A
 9: C A C D B
10: C B D C A
11: C C A B D
12: C D B A C
13: D A D B C
14: D B C A D
15: D C B D A
16: D D A C B
```

For example, since the entry in row $7$ column $3$ is D, that means that player $7$ plays on court D in round $3$.  Since players $4,10,$ and $13$ also have D's in column $3$, these $4$ players will play in the same match in round $3$.

To use the table for a three-round match, just use the first three columns.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks!  Like Tiger Wood’s swing, it looks so easy!  I will give this a try.

Comment: If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark.  That way it doesn't show up as unsolved any longer -- and my reputation goes up a little -:).

Comment: It works perfectly!  Thank you soooooo much!